# Given: $A$ ($m \times n$) and $B$ ($ n \times m$) are matrices. Prove: If $AB = I$, then $BA$ is a projection operator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I can't prove this. Does anybody have any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$BA$ is a projection operator iff it is idempotent: $(BA)^2 = BA$. Use associativity on $(BA)^2$ and you got the answer.